# How to avoid repeating a word too often when there are few synonyms for it

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to avoid repeting the word "sonnet" 3 times in a row in the same sentence. Given all the attributes and commas and also the fact that there are not many appropriate e specific synonyms for "sonnet, I am struggling a lot to do it.

This is what I think I should avoid:

> The two traditional and most popular forms of **sonnets** are the Italian,
>   or Petrarchan, **sonnet** and the English, or Shakesperean, **sonnet**.

Would this version be ok?

> The two traditional and most popular forms of **sonnets** are the Italian,
>   or Petrarchan, and the English, or Shakesperean, **sonnet**.

Or should I maybe try to use "one" instead of sonnet?

> The two traditional and most popular forms of **sonnets** are the Italian,
>   or Petrarchan, **one** and the English, or Shakesperean, **one**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with:

> The two traditional and most popular forms of sonnets are the Italian or Petrarchan, and the English or Shakespearean sonnet.

Two "sonnets" shouldn't be a problem. Also you don't need so many commas.